# How to create Table using TableContainer in Dojo in a specific format

Tags: dojo

Can we use `dojox/layout/TableContainer` to show a table with Headers and multiple rows eg.

```
 Id    ||       Header1              ||     Header2

 1     ||     Editable-TextBox1      ||   Combobox1        
 2     ||     Editable-TextBox2      ||   Combobox1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use table container to create a table like HTML. Please go through below link which explains what a table container is and how to create one.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/TableContainer.html

Comment: I have seen this link but this doesnt show to create headers and how to handle String[] of editable text boxes and comboxes. Also how to handle  columns like ID which is completely not editable .

Comment: I was able to do this with data grid but the problem with data grid is that it needs to clicked once to see if there is a combo box there for editing or a text box.And if there is a combo box then you need to click again to open that drop down  to see the possible values. The client just wants basic text boxes or combo boxes instead of complex data grid and hence i thought i would create a table instead of data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the attached image. I have used table container which contains editable textbox and also radio buttons by folowing the links that I had posted earlier i.e.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/TableContainer.html

[image: Dojo Table]

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use TableContainer, this would not be that easy as TableContainer is intended to display individual widgets, each one with its header.

In your case, headers are the cells in the first row of the table. So you could:

- disable headers (showLabels set to false)
- first provide as many disabled TextBoxes as there are columns, with their value set to the respective column header text to fill the first row
- then provide the content widgets to fill the content rows

Finally,

- the look may not be what you need, knowing TableContainer is limited in this respect.
- you would have to handle the changes logics: get back the value of each individual content widget that has changed (or of all content widgets)

Have you considered using dgrid  ? See an example [here](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Editor_more_widgets.html). The associated source code is a good starting point